# What article is correct to use in the following sntence? "the" or "a" or none

Tags: articles, definite-article

What article should I use here?

"Scored 2 goals in **the** second half of his last game";

or "Scored 2 goals in **a** second half of his last game";

or without any? "Scored 2 goals in second half of his last game".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct:

> Scored 2 goals in the second half of his last game

The reason is that we use **the** before superlatives (like *most*) and ordinal numbers (*first, **second,** third,* etc.).

> a. The most-controlled therapy yielded the best results.
> b. The first studies were conducted in early 1993.
> c. The last security conference was termed a success,
>
> —John M. Swales, Christine B. Feak: *Academic Writing for Graduate Students*

It is useful to learn the rules about superlatives and ordinals as a single rule because the *-st* ending applies to most superlatives *and* the ordinal number *first*.